# ASP: Listview buttons do nothing

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a listview control databound to a database in my ASP project and I have it set so that it can be edited. The listview is inside a multiview and it loads the information perfectly but clicking on the edit button doesn't do anything. The listview is in an update panel which I though might be part of it but putting the listview outside the update panel just causes the multivew to change view back the default page load view.

I have a perfectly functional editable listview in a previous project in almost identical circumstances and I just can't figure out what's made this one not work. I've tried deleting and remaking but this problem seems to be affecting any listview I make in the multiview. On other listviews where I've implemented the 'insert' feature, the insert button does not do anything either.

My code is below:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="StudentID" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource10" GroupItemCount="3">
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <td runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;color: #284775;">
                            StudentID:
                            <asp:Label ID="StudentIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            CurrentSchoolID:
                            <asp:Label ID="CurrentSchoolIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("CurrentSchoolID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Gender:
                            <asp:Label ID="GenderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Gender") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Fname:
                            <asp:Label ID="FnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Lname:
                            <asp:Label ID="LnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            ParentCarer:
                            <asp:Label ID="ParentCarerLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("ParentCarer") %>' />
                            <br />
                            StAddress:
                            <asp:Label ID="StAddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StAddress") %>' />
                            <br />
                            suburb:
                            <asp:Label ID="suburbLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("suburb") %>' />
                            <br />
                            postCode:
                            <asp:Label ID="postCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("postCode") %>' />
                            <br />
                            DOB:
                            <asp:Label ID="DOBLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DOB") %>' />
                            <br />
                            homePhone:
                            <asp:Label ID="homePhoneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("homePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            MobilePhone:
                            <asp:Label ID="MobilePhoneLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("MobilePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            WorkPhone:
                            <asp:Label ID="WorkPhoneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WorkPhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            email:
                            <asp:Label ID="emailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>' />
                            <br />
                            UserID:
                            <asp:Label ID="UserIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Username:
                            <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <td runat="server" style="background-color: #999999;">
                            StudentID:
                            <asp:Label ID="StudentIDLabel1" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("StudentID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            CurrentSchoolID:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentSchoolIDTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("CurrentSchoolID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Gender:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="GenderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Fname:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="FnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Lname:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="LnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            ParentCarer:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ParentCarerTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("ParentCarer") %>' />
                            <br />
                            StAddress:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StAddressTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("StAddress") %>' />
                            <br />
                            suburb:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="suburbTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("suburb") %>' />
                            <br />
                            postCode:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="postCodeTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("postCode") %>' />
                            <br />
                            DOB:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DOBTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>' />
                            <br />
                            homePhone:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="homePhoneTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("homePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            MobilePhone:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="MobilePhoneTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("MobilePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            WorkPhone:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="WorkPhoneTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("WorkPhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            email:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="emailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>' />
                            <br />
                            UserID:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Username:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                                Text="Update" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                Text="Cancel" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <table runat="server" 
                            style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    No data was returned.</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <EmptyItemTemplate>
                        <td runat="server" />
                    </EmptyItemTemplate>
                    <GroupTemplate>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                            <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </GroupTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <td runat="server" style="">
                            CurrentSchoolID:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentSchoolIDTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("CurrentSchoolID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Gender:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="GenderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Gender") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Fname:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="FnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Lname:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="LnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            ParentCarer:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ParentCarerTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("ParentCarer") %>' />
                            <br />
                            StAddress:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StAddressTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("StAddress") %>' />
                            <br />
                            suburb:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="suburbTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("suburb") %>' />
                            <br />
                            postCode:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="postCodeTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("postCode") %>' />
                            <br />
                            DOB:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DOBTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB") %>' />
                            <br />
                            homePhone:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="homePhoneTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("homePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            MobilePhone:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="MobilePhoneTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("MobilePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            WorkPhone:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="WorkPhoneTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("WorkPhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            email:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="emailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>' />
                            <br />
                            UserID:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Username:
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                                Text="Insert" />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                                Text="Clear" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <td runat="server" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
                            StudentID:
                            <asp:Label ID="StudentIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            CurrentSchoolID:
                            <asp:Label ID="CurrentSchoolIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("CurrentSchoolID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Gender:
                            <asp:Label ID="GenderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Gender") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Fname:
                            <asp:Label ID="FnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Lname:
                            <asp:Label ID="LnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            ParentCarer:
                            <asp:Label ID="ParentCarerLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("ParentCarer") %>' />
                            <br />
                            StAddress:
                            <asp:Label ID="StAddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StAddress") %>' />
                            <br />
                            suburb:
                            <asp:Label ID="suburbLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("suburb") %>' />
                            <br />
                            postCode:
                            <asp:Label ID="postCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("postCode") %>' />
                            <br />
                            DOB:
                            <asp:Label ID="DOBLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DOB") %>' />
                            <br />
                            homePhone:
                            <asp:Label ID="homePhoneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("homePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            MobilePhone:
                            <asp:Label ID="MobilePhoneLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("MobilePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            WorkPhone:
                            <asp:Label ID="WorkPhoneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WorkPhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            email:
                            <asp:Label ID="emailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>' />
                            <br />
                            UserID:
                            <asp:Label ID="UserIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Username:
                            <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <table runat="server">
                            <tr runat="server">
                                <td runat="server">
                                    <table ID="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" 
                                        style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                        <tr ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr runat="server">
                                <td runat="server" 
                                    style="text-align: center;background-color: #5D7B9D;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #FFFFFF">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <SelectedItemTemplate>
                        <td runat="server" 
                            style="background-color: #E2DED6;font-weight: bold;color: #333333;">
                            StudentID:
                            <asp:Label ID="StudentIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            CurrentSchoolID:
                            <asp:Label ID="CurrentSchoolIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("CurrentSchoolID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Gender:
                            <asp:Label ID="GenderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Gender") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Fname:
                            <asp:Label ID="FnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Lname:
                            <asp:Label ID="LnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lname") %>' />
                            <br />
                            ParentCarer:
                            <asp:Label ID="ParentCarerLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("ParentCarer") %>' />
                            <br />
                            StAddress:
                            <asp:Label ID="StAddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StAddress") %>' />
                            <br />
                            suburb:
                            <asp:Label ID="suburbLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("suburb") %>' />
                            <br />
                            postCode:
                            <asp:Label ID="postCodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("postCode") %>' />
                            <br />
                            DOB:
                            <asp:Label ID="DOBLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DOB") %>' />
                            <br />
                            homePhone:
                            <asp:Label ID="homePhoneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("homePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            MobilePhone:
                            <asp:Label ID="MobilePhoneLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("MobilePhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            WorkPhone:
                            <asp:Label ID="WorkPhoneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("WorkPhone") %>' />
                            <br />
                            email:
                            <asp:Label ID="emailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>' />
                            <br />
                            UserID:
                            <asp:Label ID="UserIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
                            <br />
                            Username:
                            <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </SelectedItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource10" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Student] WHERE [StudentID] = @StudentID" 
                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Student] ([CurrentSchoolID], [Gender], [Fname], [Lname], [ParentCarer], [StAddress], [suburb], [postCode], [DOB], [homePhone], [MobilePhone], [WorkPhone], [email], [UserID], [Username]) VALUES (@CurrentSchoolID, @Gender, @Fname, @Lname, @ParentCarer, @StAddress, @suburb, @postCode, @DOB, @homePhone, @MobilePhone, @WorkPhone, @email, @UserID, @Username)" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Student] WHERE ([Username] = @Username)" 
                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Student] SET [CurrentSchoolID] = @CurrentSchoolID, [Gender] = @Gender, [Fname] = @Fname, [Lname] = @Lname, [ParentCarer] = @ParentCarer, [StAddress] = @StAddress, [suburb] = @suburb, [postCode] = @postCode, [DOB] = @DOB, [homePhone] = @homePhone, [MobilePhone] = @MobilePhone, [WorkPhone] = @WorkPhone, [email] = @email, [UserID] = @UserID, [Username] = @Username WHERE [StudentID] = @StudentID">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="StudentID" Type="Int32" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CurrentSchoolID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Fname" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Lname" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ParentCarer" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="StAddress" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="suburb" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="postCode" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DOB" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="homePhone" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="MobilePhone" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="WorkPhone" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="Username" SessionField="Username" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="CurrentSchoolID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Fname" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Lname" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ParentCarer" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="StAddress" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="suburb" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="postCode" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DOB" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="homePhone" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="MobilePhone" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="WorkPhone" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="StudentID" Type="Int32" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# Code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Student"))
            {

                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;


            }

            else if (User.IsInRole("Staff"))
            {

                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 6;


            }

            else if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {

                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 7;


            }


        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

changed my code on page load to:

```
 if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){

    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }
```

Now works fine